# How to prevent the select tag to auto select the first option?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, html5-video

I want to add a floating placeholder for the select tag. But the select tag is choosing the fist option by default. I don't want to put an extra option without the value in the list.

Comment: so what you need? you can append a default value in the beginning of `select` list like `--select--`

Comment: I don't want to add a empty or default value in my option. I want it like a placeholder.

Comment: what do you mean by place holder, like how exactly you need?

Comment: Like, I want to add a place holder like thing in select tag. And it should not have any empty vslu option or disabled option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```html
<select name="tagging"> 
     <option selected="true" style='display: none'></option>
     <option value="Option A" >Option A</option>
     <option value="Option B" >Option B</option>
     <option value="Option C">Option C</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: Now the first option is selected but not visible.

Comment: actually I don't want an empty option in my list. Could you please suggest me some solution for this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<select>
   <option hidden>Placeholder</option>
   <option>Item 1</option>
   <option>Item 2</option>   
   <option>Item 3</option>
</select>
```